# How can I compare a number stored in a csname macro with another number in TeX (\ifnum)?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, auxiliary-files

Let's say I have a value stored in my aux using the csname syntax.

## Aux Contains

```
\relax
\expandafter\gdef \csname inputsectioncount@en-US\endcsname{0}
```

This is correct, because I have not added any sections within the context "en-US".

## Desired

```
\ifnum <number stored in aux> > 3\relax \tableofcontents\else Sorry, not enough sections to warrant a contents table.\fi
```

## Example

I tried different techniques to expand the `\csname` macro twice before `\ifnum` processes it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\newcounter{inputsectioncount}% latex counter, equiv of \global\newcount\inputsectioncounter\inputsectioncounter=0

% Add aux write hook
\let\latexsection\section
\def\section{\addtocounter{inputsectioncount}{1}\latexsection}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\someinput{%
  \setcounter{inputsectioncount}{0}% reset inputsectioncounter
  \def\contextid{en-US}% set context id (just a suffix to differentiate contexts)
  Hello, I just simulated inputting some file within a context. Afterwhich, I'd like to know how many sections I just added.   
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname inputsectioncount@\contextid\string\endcsname{\the\c@   inputsectioncount}}%
}
\makeatother
% Above code writes \expandafter\gdef \csname inputsectioncount@en-US\endcsname{0} to aux
% Now we can use this on next run

\newcommand\inputcontents{% Add contents lists if requirements are met (more than 3 sections within a context)
%  \expandafter\let\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\reserved@a\csname inputsectioncount@\ithlanguage\endcsname
%  \expandafter\ifnum\reserved@a>3\relax Here should be tableofcontents\fi
%  \expandafter\ifnum\csname inputsectioncount@\ithlanguage\endcsname>3\relax\tableofcontents\fi
}%

\begin{document}

\someinput
\inputcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifnum 3<0\csname inputsectioncount@en-US\endcsname\relax` should work (also on a run when the csname is not yet defined.

Comment: @egreg It does. Why does that work? This seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: why shouldn't it work? (what does your intuition suggest should happen?) `\csname inputsectioncount@en-US\endcsname` expands to `\inputsectioncount@en-US` which expands to 0 so this is `\ifnum 3<00\relax`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean 1. humans read left to right (so the order is backwards from thought) 2. `\ifnum 3<00\relax` is what I would expect. If `\inputsectioncount@en-US` expanded to 32, I would expect `\ifnum 3<032` (I suppose leading zeros are ignored? I'd like to know) 4. Why does the double expansion of `\csname` suddenly work? Was the problem not caused by number of expansions? It looks like the problem was due to the csname macro not existing. Could I have solved it with an `\@ifundefined` or `\ifx<csmacro><somesurelyunsusedname>`?

Comment: `\ifnum` expands an arbitrary number of times until it finds something that is a `<number>` to TeX, so it doesn't matter how many expansions it takes to make the number. `If \inputsectioncount@en-US expanded to 32, I would expect \ifnum 3<032 `  yes exactly that's what happens. (and 032 is the same as 32)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write the test as

```
\ifnum 3<0\csname inputsectioncount@en-US\endcsname\relax
```

Why this way and not the apparently more obvious

```
\ifnum \csname inputsectioncount@en-US\endcsname>3\relax
```

that *ought to* work? Actually, the second way will fail when the annotation in the `.aux` file has not yet been read (for instance, the `.aux` file did not exist at the beginning of the job, which is the case for the first run). It doesn't work, because if the macro resulting from `\csname` hasn't yet a definition it becomes `\relax` and

```
\ifnum\relax>3\relax
```

is illegal.

With the first code, instead, this doesn't happen: the initial zero has been added in order to cope with the case the macro hasn't yet a definition. In this case we'd obtain

```
\ifnum3<0\relax\relax
```

If, say, the annotation in the `.aux` file defines the macro to hold the value 42, then the test would become, after macro expansion

```
\ifnum3<042\relax
```

and initial zeros are ignored in number specifications.

Note that the tokens after `\ifnum` are fully expanded until finding tokens that make sense for `\ifnum`, so `\csname` gets expanded and also the macro resulting from it (if not made equal to `\relax`).

Comment: Note that the variable csname is intentional. i.e.`en-US` must be replacable-the replacement value held by `\contextid`. Outside the realm of this question, I have many context ids. Good explanation!